# PostgreSQL - C function to call webservice

Tags: c, web-services, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL 8.4. What I want to do is call a web service through a C function, enabled by an insert/update trigger and pass the NEW values in this webservice. How can I do that, I searched the web and couldn't find an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do this.   If you do you will have wonderful questions like how you handle the web service being down.  Also you will have to address what happens when your application rolls back.  You can't uncall the web service.  Also if the connection times out, your procedure will hang for quite a bit of time (retaining all locks etc) while waiting for the response which never comes.

A better approach is to use a queuing solution like pgq or pg_message_queue and queue up the data at trigger time, only to run it against the web service asynchronously.